# An efficient method for discovering finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I wrote a program to "discover", by means of constructing Cayley tables, finite groups.

Due to the method used (the one describe on the [wikipedia article for Cayley tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_table), starting with a identity skeleton) the runtime is on the order of $O(n!)$

This allows me to find small groups with order at most 12 before the time taken to generate the tables becomes impractical.

Is there a faster method for finding finite simple groups? This clearly rules out composing them as a product of smaller groups. Is there a procedure that could discover the Monster group, for example?

Answer (score 3):

There is a vast literature on computational group theory: you could start here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_group_theory.